# Laravel PHP if is homepage then <h1> tag

Tags: php, laravel, tags

I have a `<h1>` tag in my template blade, its duplicate in all pages of my website. I want to do a condition if the page is Homepage then use this `<h1>` else don't write it.
This is my header code

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
    <div class="slogan">
        <h1 id="h1" class="tlt">my h1 Tag</h1>
        <span id="span" class="tlt">" {{$slogan[0]->text}} "</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: It's better to have separate template for each page. Especially homepage.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Request::is('/')`, given that the "homepage" is on this url. The `is()` method can also accept wildcards which can be useful for stuff like `Request::is('admin/*');`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a route name for your routes, you can do like this in your view:

Route:

```
Route::get('/', ['as'=>'home', 'uses'=>'HomeController@index']);
```

In view:

```
@if(request()->route()->getName() == 'home')
   // <h1> Text for home page </h1>
@else
  //text for other pages.
@endif
```

Comment: whats the route ? my homepage is in /

Comment: `Route::get('/', ['as'=>'home', 'uses'=>'HomeController@index']);` This is your route

Comment: Show me your routes file. You can edit the question and paste it there.

Comment: error ! I did @if(request()->route()->Route::get('/', ['as'=>'home', 'uses'=>'HomeController@index']);)

Comment: No no. Not like that. Paste your route.

Comment: my homepage is in : / and in : /accueil

Comment: Please paste your route file in your question

Comment: what directory i can find it ?